# Actionscript error 1083: else is unexpected

Tags: actionscript

im trying to do a coloring app game for android and i got the error 1083. Here's my code:

```
function colorpart1(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (txt_color.text=="sky blue")
    {
    var myColor1 = new ColorTransform();
    myColor1.color = 0xFF7BF0;
    mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor1
    }
    else (txt_color.text=="purple")
    {
    var myColor3 = new ColorTransform();
    myColor3.color = a148ff;
    mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor3
    }
    else (txt_color.text=="magenta")
    {
    var myColor4 = new ColorTransform();
    myColor4.color = c34796;
    mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor4;
    }
    else (txt_color.text=="red")
    {
    var myColor5 = new ColorTransform();
    myColor5.color = e72534;
    mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor5;
    }
    else if(txt_color.text=="orange")
    {
    var myColor6 = new ColorTransform();
    myColor6.color = f17d3b;
    mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor6;
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this particular code/line(s) have the error when the others (with similar code did not):

```
else (txt_color.text=="magenta")
    {
    var myColor4 = new ColorTransform();
    myColor4.color = c34796;
    mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor4;
    }
    else (txt_color.text=="red")
    {
    var myColor5 = new ColorTransform();
    myColor5.color = e72534;
    mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor5;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `else` more than one in an `if...else..`. If you want to add more conditions then, you should use `else if` after `if` not after `else`.i.e:

```
function colorpart1(e: MouseEvent): void {
    if (txt_color.text == "sky blue") {
        var myColor1 = new ColorTransform();
        myColor1.color = 0xFF7BF0;
        mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor1
    } else if (txt_color.text == "purple") {
        var myColor3 = new ColorTransform();
        myColor3.color = a148ff;
        mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor3
    } else if (txt_color.text == "magenta") {
        var myColor4 = new ColorTransform();
        myColor4.color = c34796;
        mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor4;
    } else if (txt_color.text == "red") {
        var myColor5 = new ColorTransform();
        myColor5.color = e72534;
        mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor5;
    } else if (txt_color.text == "orange") {
        var myColor6 = new ColorTransform();
        myColor6.color = f17d3b;
        mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor6;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `else` case more than once. it's invalid. You define `var myColor` in each case. You can reduce that define by once. In below code I use `toLowerCase()` method because if `txt_color.text` return CamelCase or UPPERCASE than none of those condition satisfy.

```
   function colorpart1(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var myColor;
        if (txt_color.text.toLowerCase() == "sky blue")
        {
            myColor = new ColorTransform();
            myColor.color = 0xFF7BF0;
            mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor;
        }
        else if (txt_color.text.toLowerCase() == "purple")
        {
            myColor = new ColorTransform();
            myColor.color = 0xa148ff;
            mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor
        }
        else if (txt_color.text.toLowerCase() == "magenta")
        {
            myColor = new ColorTransform();
            myColor.color = 0xc34796;
            mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor;
        }
        else if (txt_color.text.toLowerCase() == "red")
        {
            myColor = new ColorTransform();
            myColor.color = 0xe72534;
            mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor;
        }
        else if (txt_color.text.toLowerCase() == "orange")
        {
            myColor = new ColorTransform();
            myColor.color = 0xf17d3b;
            mc_object.mc_p1.transform.colorTransform = myColor;
        }
    }
```